# Is "that" acceptable instead of "so that"?

Tags: sentence-construction

Reading *Notes from the Underground* by Fyodor Dostoyevsky. I have found this sentence:

> I was in the service that I might have something to eat

Based on my limited knowledge of English, It seems to me that it should have to be like this: *I was in the service **so that** I might have something to eat*

Can the "so" be omitted? Both forms are correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in the service that I might have something to eat.

Yes, the so may be omitted. In contemporary English we would say: so that, but omission of it was common in literary writing at the time.